# What does SO_TIMEOUT and CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS means in Netty's ChannelOption?

Tags: java, sockets, timeout, netty

What does `SO_TIMEOUT` and `CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS` mean and what is the difference between them?

I have found that: many request cost 3.004s and my handler always cost 0.003s or 0.004s and I set the `SO_TIMEOUT` to 3000 , is there a relationship among them?

I think `SO_TIMEOUT` means that when a response is not send in `SO_TIMEOUT time`, send this response immediately. Is this correct?

Answer (score 6):

- `CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS` means *timeout* value to setup a
  *connection*, this timeout is supported by Netty.
- `SO_TIMEOUT` is option for *socket*, it will impact:
  | `ServerSocket.accept();`
  | `SocketInputStream.read()`
  | `DatagramSocket.receive()`

For more details please check: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_TIMEOUT

If you just want to control *request timeout*, you could try Netty's `ReadTimeoutHandler` or `IdleTimeoutHandler`.

Comment: do you know how to use ReadTimeoutHandler WriteTimeoutHandler and IdleTimeoutHandler , I am puzzled about them . can you give me a code example ?

Answer (score 0):

SO_TIMEOUT is set by java.net.ServerSocket (OIO/BIO)
CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS is set by Netty(NIO)

`io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel`:

```
        @Override
        public void connect(
                final SocketAddress remoteAddress, final SocketAddress localAddress, final ChannelPromise promise) {
            // ...

            try {
                // ...
                if (doConnect(remoteAddress, localAddress)) {
                    fulfillConnectPromise(promise, wasActive);
                } else {
                    // ...
                    int connectTimeoutMillis = config().getConnectTimeoutMillis();
                    if (connectTimeoutMillis > 0) {
                        connectTimeoutFuture = eventLoop().schedule(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                ChannelPromise connectPromise = AbstractNioChannel.this.connectPromise;
                                ConnectTimeoutException cause =
                                        new ConnectTimeoutException("connection timed out: " + remoteAddress);
                                if (connectPromise != null && connectPromise.tryFailure(cause)) {
                                    close(voidPromise());
                                }
                            }
                        }, connectTimeoutMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    }

                    // ...
        }
```

Comment: What does SO_TIMEOUT and CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS mean ？